# сравнения в Ruby

Tags: ruby

```
x = 10      
xx = 10
```

```
1. x == xx                      #true
2. x.eql?xx                     #true
3. x.equal?xx                   #true
4. x.object_id == xx.object_id  #true
```

Бородатые дядьки объясните почему в строке 3 и 4 возвращается true.

Answer (score 4):

**Осторожно**: ответ написан, когда актуальным был MRI 2.3.
[В 2.4 `Fixnum` и `Bignum` сведены в один тип `Integer`](https://blog.heroku.com/ruby-2-4-features-hashes-integers-rounding#unified-integers). Но описываемая особенность всё ещё имеет место, просто если раньше числа ей подверженные было легко распознать по классу, теперь это глубоко закопанная деталь реализации.

---

Потому что (следуя семантике `Object#eql?` и `Object#equal?`) в `x` и `xx` **не просто равное, а одно и то же значение**, равны даже ссылки (в Ruby, напоминаю, все значения это ссылки, с парой оговорок, об одной из которых я сейчас и расскажу).

В MRI если посмотреть в `object_id` (который фактически выводит значение ссылки; самой ссылки, а не значения *за* ней), можно увидеть, что у равных `Fixnum`'ов (литерал `10` представляет один из них) одинаковые `object_id` **при любых обстоятельствах**: литерал ли это в коде, результат ли вычислений...

*Кэш? То есть, MRI кэширует объекты чисел и достаёт их по значению?*

**Почти. Но не совсем.**

### Безумные бинарные хаки

"Ссылка" на `Fixnum` в MRI содержит его значение **внутри**, прямо в ссылке. Если у большинства объектов `object_id` это указатель на объект в памяти (или *адрес объекта в памяти*), то у `Fixnum` (и у некоторых других классов) эта "ссылка", если интерпретировать её именно как указатель ведёт... куда-то, куда лучше не смотреть. Там может быть что-то интересное, а может быть чужая память. Потому что у `Fixnum`'ов это **не** указатель.

`object_id` у `Fixnum` это значение числа, сдвинутое на 1 влево, и 1 на младшем бите. Если на время забыть об отрицательных числах, то чтобы получить `object_id` любого `Fixnum`а, надо его умножить на 2 и прибавить 1.

```
(0..100_000).all? { |i| i.object_id == (i * 2 + 1) } # => true
```

С отрицательными числами всё несколько сложнее, поскольку числа хранятся в [дополнительном коде](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%94%D0%BE%D0%BF%D0%BE%D0%BB%D0%BD%D0%B8%D1%82%D0%B5%D0%BB%D1%8C%D0%BD%D1%8B%D0%B9_%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%B4_(%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%B4%D1%81%D1%82%D0%B0%D0%B2%D0%BB%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B5_%D1%87%D0%B8%D1%81%D0%BB%D0%B0)). Нужно пользоваться уже битовой арифметикой:

```
(-100_000..100_000).all? { |i| i.object_id == (i << 1 | 1) } # => true
```

Каким образом MRI догадывается, является ли значение указателем на объект в памяти или `Fixnum`ом? Очень просто, по младшему биту (на самом деле не только). В объектом пространстве Ruby не используются нечётные указатели, поскольку все типы имеют размер больше 2 байт.

---

*Чуть более наглядно (и на английском) можно почитать об этом [в этой статье](http://www.sarahmei.com/blog/2009/04/21/object-ids-and-fixnums/), а можно даже покопаться в исходном коде Ruby ([вот преобразование из `Fixnum` в сишный `long`](https://github.com/ruby/ruby/blob/8998c06461ea0bef11b3aeb30b6d2ab71c8762ba/include/ruby/ruby.h#L347)).*

*Но я здесь говорю исключительно об MRI. Гарантируется ли такое поведение во всех реализациях? Поскольку спецификации у Ruby, как у языка (а не реализации), нет, то нет.*

Comment: По первой ссылке, где на английском. Почему в первом примере `32.class.name` выводит `Fixnum`, а у меня `Integer`? Это какое-то нововведение в последних версиях? Старая статья?

Comment: @smellyshovel ага, [нововведение MRI 2.4](https://blog.heroku.com/ruby-2-4-features-hashes-integers-rounding#unified-integers). Прям самый что ни на есть свежак.

Comment: О, спасибо за инфу :)

Comment: А, я понял ваш сарказм, когда посмотрел на дату публикации :D Давненько за Руби не брался, что уж тут поделаешь

Comment: @smellyshovel никакого сарказма. Это правда свежак. И конкретно эта черта может много где сломать совместимость. Не очень получается у MRI жить по [семверу](http://semver.org/lang/ru/).

Comment: Насчет совместимости не совсем понятно почему, судя по соглашению об именовании версий. Все-таки не мажорное обновление (относительно 2.3.x, конечно же)

Comment: А, да. Вы именно об этом и сказали. Как обычно.

Comment: @smellyshovel формально совместимость не сломана, 2.4 при использовании Fixnum только сыплет предупреждениями. Но поскольку "хорошие разработчики"™ рассматривают предупреждения как ошибки, это всё равно требует починки в зависящих продуктах.