# Что такое объект в Python. Почему id(a) == id(b) == id(1)?

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-internals

Детализирую вопрос.
В книгах по Python пишут, что все в Python есть объект.

Берем традиционный подход к изучению/обучению языкам программирования.
Языки Pascal, C, C++, у них есть понятие  "имя переменной" (идентификатор). С именем переменной связывается/присваивается значение. Значение хранится в памяти. Имя переменной - это способ (в исходном тексте программы) обратиться к ячейке памяти для получения значения, которое там хранится.

Не знаю верно ли высказывание (для компилируемых языков): Для  переменных, например, целого типа, в момент выполнения программы на компьютере, процессор работает уже с адресами ячеек памяти, где хранятся значения переменных. Т.е. не такого, что где-то по какому-то адресу хранится имя переменной и оно связывается с адресом ячейки, в которой хранится значение.

Теперь переходим к Python. В этом языке все является объектом, даже определение функции.
Переменная объект, значение объект и т.д. В разное время с одним и тем же объектом может соотноситься разный другой объект.

```
a = 1
print(a)
a = "Hello"
print(a)
```

Но тогда как понять действие функции `id()`? По определению стандарта
она возвращает "identify" указанного объекта. Причем, "возвращает целое, гарантированно являющееся **уникальным**" и постоянным для объекта на время его существования."

Тогда почему

```
a = 1
b = 1
print(id(a) == id(b) == id(1))  # True
print("Why?")
```

ведь a, b, 1 разные объекты?
По-моему вопрос получился...

Используется Python 3.6

---

Про значения от -5 до 256 наслышан. Имеет место быть

```
a = 1000000
b = 1000000
print(id(a) == id(b))  # True
print("Why?")
```

На счет того, что достаточно "знать об именах и т.д.". Для меня не достаточно, потому и спрашиваю у уважаемых профи. В Питоне все объект. Нет имен переменных. Отсюда и мой вопрос.

Comment: [Аналогичный вопрос, но по Ruby](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/592477/181100). Знать о разных реализациях одного и того же может быть полезно.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

В питоне интерпретатор оптимизирован так, что небольшие целые числа представлены одним объектом - это сделано в целях улучшения производительности. Для больших чисел это уже не выполняется.

**Марк Лутц - Изучаем Python, 4-е издание, 2011, стр. 204:**

> ```
> >>> X = 42 
> >>> Y = 42  # Должно получиться два разных объекта 
> >>> X == Y
> True
>
> >>> X is Y  # Тот же самый объект: кэширование в действии!
> True
> ```
>
> В этом примере переменные `X` и `Y` должны быть равны (==, одно и то же 
>   значение), но не эквивалентны (`is`, один и тот же объект), потому что
>   было  выполнено два разных литеральных выражения. Однако из-за того,
>   что малые целые  числа и строки кэшируются и используются повторно,
>   оператор `is` сообщает,  что переменные ссылаются на один и тот же
>   объект.

Comment: 1- Реализации Питона такие как CPython, Pypy, Jython могут закэшировать (intern) маленькие целые, но в общем случае Питон не обязан это делать и одинаково-корректное поведение между реализациями может быть *разным* (попробуйте  `a=-6` на CPython и Pypy). 2- "литеральные выражения"  вовсе не обязаны *разные* объекты создавать даже для больших целых. Посмотрите явный пример для `a=1000000` [в моём ответе](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/662407/23044).

Answer (score 15):

> В разное время с одним и тем же объектом может соотноситься разный другой объект.

Вы хотели сказать: *в разное время, одно и то же **имя** может ссылаться на разные объекты*

Модель в Питоне простая — совершенно не нужно знать что такое адрес, ячейка памяти, указатель. Достаточно знать только  об именах и объектах, к которым они привязаны.

Вот [картинки, которые поясняют разницу между переменными в С подобных языках и именами в Питоне.](https://web.archive.org/web/20180411011411/http://python.net/~goodger/projects/pycon/2007/idiomatic/handout.html#other-languages-have-variables) Ярлыки и шарики достаточны, чтобы любое поведение на уровне Питона объяснить — сперва не верится что такая простая модель все крайние случаи охватывает.

> ведь a, b, 1 разные объекты?

У вас только один объект (единица). Маленькие целые кэшируются в CPython. Разные *имена* a, b ссылаются на один и тот же объект: `a is b` (`id(a) == id(b)`). `1` это константа в исходном коде (думайте как о вызове конструктора для объекта). Подробнее об `int` объектах: [Присваивание в Python](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/571490/23044).

> a = 1000000; b = 1000000; print (id(a) == id(b)) # True

Для проверки ссылаются ли имена на одни и те же объекты, используйте `a is b` (здесь это равнозначно `id(a) == id(b)`, но `id` может быть переопределён в общем случае).

Результат может быть `True` (зависит как Питон код был в байт-код скомпилирован в выбранной реализации), но не обязан быть `True`:

```
>>> a = 1000000
>>> b = 1000000
>>> print (a is b) 
False
```

В данном случае, каждое выражение отдельно компилируется, `a` и `b` на разные объекты ссылаются. Сравните:

```
>>> def f():
...     a = 1000000
...     b = 1000000
...     print(a is b)

>>> f()
True
```

Код функции как одно целое компилируется, поэтому `a is b` *может* (но не обязано) быть `True`. Один это объект или несколько может зависеть от реализации Питона (CPython, Pypy, Jython, etc) и даже конкретной версии реализации. Реальный код не должен зависеть от подобных деталей реализации. [Как явно сказано по ссылке](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/571490/23044): не используйте проверку на идентичность для сравнения чисел (разные объекты могут иметь одно значение). Используйте `a == b`, чтобы узнать равны ли числа.

> Питоне все объект. Нет имен переменных. Отсюда и мой вопрос.

Конечно в Питоне есть имена. `a` и  `b` это имена в вашем вопросе.

То что кодом Питона в разных представлениях можно манипулировать как простым объектом (в функцию передать как параметр, вернуть из функции, вызвать методы, итд) никак не отменяет наличие имён.

Примеры:

- [на уровне AST](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9558001/4279) — имена это узлы типа `_ast.Name`. Более сложный пример это [MacroPy](https://macropy3.readthedocs.io/en/latest/overview.html)
- [на уровне байт-кода (byteplay)](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/652521/23044)
- исходного кода (lib2to3)

Также, для манипуляций Питон кода, может быть полезно знать о compile(), eval(), exec() встроенных функциях, dis, [uncompyle6](https://github.com/rocky/python-uncompyle6/blob/master/HISTORY.md), inspect модулях. К примеру, [`inspect.signature()` позволяет манипулировать описанием функции как объектом.](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/656776/23044) В уже упомянутой ссылке показано как [саму память, занимаемую объектом в CPython реализации, можно также как обычным Питон объектом манипулировать с помощью ctypes (пример изменяет неизменяемый на уровне Питона объект типа int)](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/571490/23044).

Comment: a = 1000000
    b = 1000000
    print (id(a) == id(b))  # True
    print ("Why?")

Comment: Спасибо за картинки. Он поясняют Вашу правильную мысль. Но они не соответствуют описанию Питона в книгах. Но они ПРАВИЛЬНЫЕ. Просто надо переписывать  доки  к Питону. Получается, что не все в Питоне ОБЪЕКТ.

Comment: @Молодойеще: всё в Питоне объект.  Если хотите вы можете [AST](http://stackoverflow.com/a/9558001/4279) (пример, [macropy](https://github.com/lihaoyi/macropy#30000ft-overview)) или [байт-кодом (byteplay) манипулировать](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/652521/23044) на лету.

Comment: Тогда. что такое имя? Какой это объект?

Comment: @Молодойеще: я не верю, что вы за 3 минуты, смогли прочитать и понять приведённые ссылки. Особенно на картинки в описании macrpy посмотрите.

Comment: Вообще-то довольно быстро и прочитать и понять. Когда знаешь что ищешь.

Comment: @Молодойеще: мне заметно больше 3 минут потребовалось, чтобы понять, что такое macropy и как оно работает. Кстати, не стесняйтесь вопросы задавать ("что такое имя? Какой это объект?" -- это отличный вопрос (напомнило [Richard Feynman. Why.](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=36GT2zI8lVA)). В данном случае, ответ скучный: в AST представлен типом `_ast.Name`), просто старайтесь ответы не забывать читать также.

Answer (score 1):

1. переменные хранят **только ссылки** на объект
2. оператор `=` **присваивает** переменной **ссылку**
3. примитивные типы (**литералы**: числа, строки) с одинаковым значением **представлены единственным объектом**

Comment: Это неправильно.

Comment: 3 - нет: https://i.stack.imgur.com/f0bIb.png

Answer (score 0):

Я думаю лучше посмотреть на иерархию классов или типов Python.
Они все начинаются с базового типа, который называется **object**. Ну и у них есть некоторые методы, которые называются дандер методами. Начинаются и заканчиваются на двойное подчёркивание.

Тут важно ещё отметить про пространства имён. В python их много. Например функция, класс, модуль - это всё пространства имён. За одним именем что-то да хранится.

Что касается чисел, то числа - неизменяемые. То есть когда ты присваиваешь какое-то число какой-то переменной - оно кладётся в память как есть. А счётчик ссылок увеличивается на 1. Когда ты пытаешься второй раз присвоить это число какой-то переменной - оно не создаётся. Просто счётчик ссылок увеличивается ещё на 1.

Соответственно, когда ты удаляешь число - счётчик ссылок уменьшается на 1. Когда счётчик станет равным 0 - сборщик мусора удалит этот объект.

Итак почему всё в python является объектом? Потому что наследуется от класса **object**. Даже базовые типы типа **int, str**.

Почему:

```py
a = 1
b = 1
print(id(a) == id(b) == id(1))
```

Потому, что 1 создаётся 1 раз при объявлении а = 1. И дальше а просто ссылается на 1.
А когда создаётся b, 1 уже существует, так как на неё есть одна ссылка. И b просто ссылается на туже единицу.

На самом деле единица в python много где используется и если посмотреть количество ссылок на неё, то их будет много.
Также **True** является псевдонимом для 1.

Если хочешь лучше изучить тему почитай про иерархию классов \ типов python, об областях видимости и о работе сборщика мусора.

Comment: Это вообще никак не связано с иерахирей классов. Числа от -50 до 128 в единственном экземпляре существуют, т.е. они синглтоны фактически. Это особенность реализации CPython. Количество ссылок на них бессмысленно смотреть, эти объекты не удаляются никогда.

Comment: Почитайте по ссылке, там вообще великий текст, в частности и про этот кейс тоже https://github.com/satwikkansal/wtfpython#-how-not-to-use-is-operator

Comment: Пардон, ошибся, не от -50 до 128, а от -5 до 256 включительно https://i.stack.imgur.com/DBicQ.png https://i.stack.imgur.com/uZO3P.png

Comment: Эти числа не связаны с иерархией классов python. Но вопрос, который интересовал ТС в том, почему всё в Python является объектом. Ему нужно было общее понимание, а не знание особенностей реализации CPython.
Для общего понимания этими числами вообще можно пренебречь и почитать по указанным выше темам.

Comment: "Итак почему всё в python является объектом? Потому что наследуется от класса object." - из второго не следует первое. Скорее наоборот, автором языка было принято решение, что все в Python - это объекты, поэтому они наследуются от object. Чтобы сделать, чтобы "сущность" наследовалась от object (в принципе, могла наследоваться от чего-то), она уже должна быть объектом.