# Можно ли переопределить квадратные скобки в Python?

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-2.x, python-internals

Можно ли каким-то образом сделать так, чтобы `[]` в Python ассоциировались 
 не с листом, а с каким-либо другим классом?

Comment: А можно поинтересоваться, зачем?

Comment: Мне просто стало интересно, но я не смог нагуглить ответ)

Comment: Numpy и Pandas во всю этим пользуются... Поясните что вы хотите сделать.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Можно. К примеру, используя [`codetransformer` пакет](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/codetransformer):

```
from codetransformer import CodeTransformer, instructions, pattern

class BuildSetFromList(CodeTransformer):
    @pattern(instructions.BUILD_LIST)
    def _build_set(self, _build_list):
        yield instructions.LOAD_GLOBAL("set")
        yield instructions.CALL_FUNCTION()

@BuildSetFromList()
def f():
    return []

assert f() == set()
```

Вместо списка, `[]` создают `set()` здесь.

Есть ещё несколько других способов, см.  [начиная с *"кодом Питона в разных представлениях можно манипулировать как простым объектом"*](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/662407/23044).

Comment: Ок, и теперь у нас `>>> type(f()) -> <class 'set'>` но `>>> type([]) -> <class 'list'>` не уверен, что это называеться  "можно". За либу спасибо, интересно

Comment: @IgorSergeevich: (а) смотрим внутрь `f()`: `return []` видим квадратные скобки (возражений нет? согласны?). (б) Затем вызываем `f()` как вы уже сами признали `f() == set()` (с) из `(а)` и `(б)` следует утвердительный ответ на вопрос *"Можно ли переопределить квадратные скобки в Python?"* (Питон код — ✓, `[]` — ✓,  получили не список — ✓вывод: можно). Область действия в которой `[]` переопределено может варьироваться от выбранного способа, но сомнений нет, что `[]` переопределено (в примере, в вопросе внутри функции `f` -- вы не можете сказать, что это не Питон-код, что `[]` не переопределены).

Answer (score 2):

Сделать так, чтобы `[]` вообще нельзя было применить к списку - нельзя. Сделать `[]` применимыми к объекту пользовательского класса - можно, причем совершенно не обязательно, чтобы скобки имели семантику индексации

```
class IsEven:
    def __init__(self):
        pass

    def __getitem__(self, item):
        return item % 2 == 0


x = IsEven()
print x[1], x[2] # --> False True
```

---

Если речь о том, чтобы вызов конструктора имел синтаксис генератора списков - нельзя.

Comment: вопрос не о том как переопределить индексацию: `seq[index]`, а о том как сделать, чтобы `[]` вернули не `list()`, а что-то другое.

Comment: "вопрос не о том как переопределить индексацию: seq[index], а о том как сделать, чтобы [] вернули не list(), а что-то другое"                                                                                                                 Сделай чтобы []== ().

Comment: "вы не можете сказать, что это не Питон-код, что [] не переопределены"  Квадратные скобки в Python нельзя переопределить из Python.