# Что означает - SyntaxError: can't assign to literal

Tags: python

Когда я пытаюсь выполнить этот код, у меня вылезает ошибка

> "can't assign to literal"

```
 1 = 'Нет - ****** ответ!'
```

Вот. Может, не знаю, надо переменную ставить не как число? но это вряд ли, потому что Питон выделяет красным именно пустое пространство от символа "'" и до конца того, что я вижу справа. Что за фигня, спрашивается?

Comment: версия питона 3.4.4

Comment: надо было вставить код вот так:

Comment: `1 = 'Нет - ****** ответ!' `

Comment: Я уже разобралась, хех, ведь попробовать не помешает никогда

Answer (score 6):

[Имена в Питоне](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/lexical_analysis.html#identifiers) не могут на цифры начинаться, поэтому `1` здесь интерпретируется как число (константа):

```
$ python -mtokenize <<<'1 = ".."' 
1,0-1,1:            NUMBER         '1'            
1,2-1,3:            OP             '='            
1,4-1,8:            STRING         '".."'         
1,8-1,9:            NEWLINE        '\n'           
2,0-2,0:            ENDMARKER      ''
```

Поменять, что `1` означает в исходном коде таким способом нельзя. Поэтому SyntaxError возникает. На старых версиях Питона, можно было изменить к каким объектам `True`, `False` имена прикреплены (в современных версиях это ключевые слова. Всегда: `True == 1` и `False == 0`). В образовательных целях, можно попробовать [поменять объект int, соответствующий константе,](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/571490/23044) или даже [сам код трансформировать](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/718426/23044).

Оператор присваивания достаточно интересный в Питоне. Попробуйте представить [как `[] = []` работает](https://ideone.com/OsO3w4) (или в качестве бонуса: [`(a, b) = a[b] = {}, 5`](https://twitter.com/fijall/status/634260102795685890)). Экспериментировать с казалось бы бессмысленными конструкциями полезно, чтобы границы понимания, реализаций обнаружить (буквально подобный код не стоит использовать).

Answer (score 2):

Это можно сделать так:

```
>>> globals()[1] = 'Нет - ****** ответ!'
>>> print(globals()[1])
Нет - ****** ответ!
```

Или так:

```
>>> locals()[1] = 'Нет - ****** ответ!'
>>> print(locals()[1])
Нет - ****** ответ!
```

Но не очень понятно, зачем.

Comment: Ой, вопрос протухший, оказывается. Ну ничего, пусть будет.

Comment: на вопрос можно хоть через 10 лет ответить. Основная аудитория  Stack Overflow (~95%) это посетители из гугла. Нельзя публиковать ответы, только на закрытые вопросы (вопросы, неподходящие для SO).  Я получаю плюсы на ответы, которые ещё в 2008 дал.

Answer (score 1):

Вы пытаетесь числу задать какое то значение но это в априоре невозможно! невозможно сохранити какуюто информацию в число, для этого создаются переменные в которых хранится путь к памяти в которой хранится это значение.

Вы должны число 1 сделать переменной!