# Как работают переменные в Python?

Tags: python, выделение-памяти

Начал изучение Python и возник следующий вопрос:
Как в Python работают указатели? - как при присвоении одинакового значения - переменны начинают указывать на один и тот же участок памяти.
Поясню на примере:

`a=1 b=1`

В видеоуроках, которые я смотрю -утверждается следующее - что эти переменные будут указывать на один участок памяти. Мне не совсем понятно, как это реализовано в самом Python ? Например, в с++ очевидно, что `a=&b` - это указатель на один участок памяти, НО данный код - пишется программистом - т.е вся логика продумывается человеком. Как это работает в Python  - неужели он сравнивает все значения - именно как значения - и если они совпадают - неявно выполняет операцию `a=&b` ?

Comment: В питоне нет указателей.

Comment: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/662398 - тут частично раскрывается то, о чем вы спрашиваете.

Comment: Ну а вообще, все, что нужно знать о работе с памятью в питоне - это то, что этой самой работы нет вообще. Единственное взаимодействие с памятью, которое позволяется разработчику - это получение id(obj), которое показывает, хранятся ли разные объекты в одном месте или в разных.

Comment: @EzikBro, благодарю  - ссылка действительно помогла.

Answer (score -2):

Разобрался благодаря этой теме на англйском SO:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13530998/are-python-variables-pointers-or-else-what-are-they
- просто не сразу понял концепцию привязки в питоне.

Всем спасибо за минусы к вопросу - иногда, я просто обожаю SO - вместо того что бы объяснить человеку в чем он не прав - молчаливый минус в карму.