# Почему в python меняется id для переменной?

Tags: python, python-3.x

```
a = 101

while True:
    a -= 1
    input(f'You have {a} apple {id(a)}')
```

Comment: Потому что это не id переменной, а id объекта хранящегося в этой переменной.

Comment: почитайте [здесь](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/662398/209304) может найдете ответ

Comment: Фукция id возвращает идентификатор объекта в памяти. Переменная ссылается на этот объект. Изменение значения будет означать, что будет создан новый объект со своим id и переменная станет указывать уже на него.