# Запись в побайтовом режиме Ruby

Tags: ruby

Как записать файл в побайтовом режиме в Ruby? Cчитать смог но записать не знаю как, даже если открывать в режиме `"wb"`.

Вот код того как считываю:

```
def main
  file = File.open('text.txt', 'rb')
  #puts file.all?
  text = []
  until file.eof?
    text.append(file.readbyte)
  end
  print text
  #[72, 101, 108, 108, 111, 32, 119, 111, 114, 108, 100, 33] то что получилось
end
main
```

И как мне записать этот массив байтов в новый файл так, чтобы получился точно такой же файл, который я считал?

Comment: Полученный массив байтов будет преобразовываться перед записью? Какую задачу решаете (возможно есть более быстрый и экономный способ)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Чтобы работать максимально аналогично чтению, отдельный байт можно записать с помощью [метода `IO#putc`](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.4.0/IO.html#method-i-putc), доступного в т. ч. у объектов класса `File` через наследование.

```
file = File.open('text.txt', 'rb')
out  = File.open('out.txt',  'wb')
#puts file.all?
text = []
until file.eof?
  byte = file.readbyte
  text.append(byte)
  out.putc(byte)
end
```

---

Но имейте в виду, массивы байт в Ruby обычно представляют в форме **строк** в кодировке `ASCII-8BIT` (у которой есть псевдоним `BINARY`). И не просто так.

Массив целых чисел в MRI, канонической реализации, в разы объёмнее из-за [своеобразного способа хранения](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/592483/181100): каждое число занимает объём как минимум одной полноценной ссылки, а он равен разрядности, под которую скомпилирован интерпретатор Ruby. То есть, можно ожидать разницы объёма, грубо, в 4-8 раз.

И если вас такая разница беспокоит, то отдельно следите за тем, где строки копируются, и в критичных местах используйте методы, изменяющие саму строку, а не возвращающие изменённую копию.

Answer (score 0):

Вы переводите код каждого байта в десятичное представление, чтобы собрать из полученного массива снова бинарную строку, к каждому байту нужно применить метод `ord`, а элементы массива соединить в строку при помощи метода `join`.

Для того, чтобы записать полученные данные в файл достаточно открыть его в бинарном режиме и записать в него полученную строку

```
def main
  File.open('text.txt', 'rb') do |file|
    [].tap { |text| text << file.readbyte until file.eof? }
  end
end

# Преобразование массива

File.open('text.out', 'wb') do |f|
  f.print main.map(&:chr).join
end
```